# How to make lua_ls provide completion for luasnip methods?

Tags: neovim, autocompletion, lsp, plugin-luasnip, plugin-nvim-cmp

I am using luasnip in Neovim and I'm having problems getting `lua_ls` to provide information about the functions.

```lua
local ls = require("luasnip")
local s = ls.snippet
```

Basically, I want when writing `s(..)` see the parameters and the different parts of the method that I am working with.

Instead I get nothing.

I have my current setup here https://github.com/Darkfrobozz/nvim